# Debug MongoDB queries with the C# driver v2 API

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Can I serialize a `FilterDefinition<T>` to a json string to see what is being built under the hood? Or only via the logs and a more verbose database profiler setting?

Comment: Who keeps downvoting this question??? It's perfectly legit...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, FilterDefinition has a Render method on it. Provided you have access to the collection you are using, you can do the following.

```
var renderedFilter = definition.Render(collection.DocumentSerializer, collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry);
```

It will render to a BsonDocument, what you can use ToString() on that if you want the JSON.

Comment: Thanks! The parameters threw me off in the standard API documentation without further knowledge.